# This SVG is invalid. Validate it before opening

Tags: svg, adobe-illustrator

I just modified a svg file that came with my Wordpress Template but i come up to this: Error Line 787, Column 77: there is no attribute "sketch:type"

```
<g id="city-copy" transform="translate(1305.000000, 47.000000)" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup">
```

Comment: Have you removed the xmlns for sketch? Or did you add sketch:type? "I modified a file" is rather vague. What was it before? And what modifications did you make exactly?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information, i mean that i edited the image in illustrator ( i removed an element, a tree ) saved the file again as svg and now i cant open it, it says "This SVG is invalid. Validate it before opening" . The error i posted is from an online validation tool.

Answer (score 6):

Open the svg in a text editor and remove the `sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"` attribute from the `<g>` element. An even better maneuver would be to optimize your svg with a tool like [svgo](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/).

Answer (score 4):

Check the encoding value.

I changed the `encoding="windows-1252"` to `encoding="utf-8"` and worked for me.

Comment: There is no encoding attribute in the question.

Comment: The string `"sketch:type"` which is marked by the online validation tool is encoded by the same byte sequence, whether the encoding is UTF-8 or Windows-1252. Hence, that can't be the solution to the OP's problem.

Comment: My SVG file already had `encoding="utf-8"` in its header. The problem turned out to be the FILE was not properly UTF-8 encoded. So I ran a conversion to UTF-8 in my text editor, saved, and then the SVG file opened perfectly in Illustrator CS6. Thanks Robert L - your comment led me to this answer :)

Answer (score 4):

This can be caused by a variety of things but I've been able to solve this by:

1. open the SVG in [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org)
2. Go To File > Clean Up Document
3. Save the SVG (choose a unique file name so you do not lose your previous work).

Answer (score 2):

guys! I saw this tip on another forum, and it worked. I managed to fix the corrupted file. What you have to do is:

- Open the file in a text-editor (I used Dreawweaver)
- Check the first line for entries like:  xmlns:x="&ns_extend;" xmlns:i="&ns_ai;" xmlns:graph="&ns_graphs;", and delete the '&' characters so it reads: xmlns:x="ns_extend;" xmlns:i="ns_ai;" xmlns:graph="ns_graphs;"
- Save the file, and Illustrator will open it.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks much for the how-to principle. In my situation, using that idea (of opening the corrupted SVG file with a text editor since Adobe Illustrator wouldn't open the file), I used a text editor (Smultron) to open both the corrupted SVG file and an openable SVG file. I compared the upper area of both files; saw that certain lines of code were missing from the corrupted SVG file; copied those few extra lines of code from the openable (working) SVG; and saved. AI could then open the formerly corrupted SVG file. I copied the layers I needed into a new AI file and abandoned the formerly corrupted SVG.

Answer (score 0):

AI version CS7 is saving invalid SVG and SVGZ files. In my case, two namespaces were missing from the SVG file.

Use the Export to SVG instead. It save the SVG without the need for namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with svg files that I had saved in Adobe Illustrator. The easy fix for me was to open the files in Inkscape and save a copy, and these files are fine.

The original error message said "The SVG file is invalid. Validate it before opening." The ironic thing is that after saving a copy with a new name, the original files will now open in  Illustrator.

Answer (score 0):

As a complete non-techy, I followed the advice above and opened my SVG in text editor. None of the problems above were in my file so I compared the file to a working SVG file, trialed a few things and discovered that
" 0 0 no-repeat
at the very end of the code outside of the  tag was the culprit! Deleted this and voila! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Wow, so many different answers! Might as well add my own... This is handled the error in Adobe Illustrator when opening a file downloaded from the internet, might work in other scenarios as well.

I opened the svg in a text editor and noticed that the [XML prolog](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp) at the beginning did not match a different, working, file. Specifically the non-working one was version 1.1 and did not include the `standalone="no"` attribute. So the fixed prolog now reads:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no">`

Worked for me!

Answer (score -1):

After opening my svg in a code/text editor, in my case Visual Studio Code I noticed that mine had `<DIV id="container">` and `</DIV>` surrounding the `<svg..... >` data.

Removing this div tag solved my issue.

Answer (score -1):

I stumbled on another easy fix by luck: I was about to open an SVG in a text editor, when I noticed that OSX was defaulting SVGs to [ImageOptim](https://imageoptim.com/mac), an app I use for stripping metadata, etc. So I let that have the file, and a moment later I had a valid SVG file that took up 68% less space on disk.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem, which was not solved by any of the above mentioned solutions. In the end I solved it by unchecking the box 'Export RDF metadata' when creating the SVG file (in QGIS in this case).

Most likely something in the RDF metadata must have been unreadable for Illustrator, but I didn't manage to figure out what part exactly.